# A broad question about identity card tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-renaming

Our primary identity card tag is [identity-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-cards). I had a hard time finding it because I typed [id-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id-card). Could we add [id-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id-card) as a synonym? Maybe [state-id](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-id) too?

---

The EU specific tag is [eu-id-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-id-card).

1. It should be plural; [eu-id-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-id-cards).
2. It should not be too different from [identity-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-cards); [eu-identity-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu-identity-cards) is what it should be.

---

Anyone agreeing?